# How to put this sign in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

The sign is in this image: [Unterschrift Kunde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYfwQ.png)

This is my first question; thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are asking about [Ballot X](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2717/index.htm).  In LibreOffice 5.1 and higher, type `U+2717` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

For Apache OpenOffice and older versions of LibreOffice, go to `Insert -> Special Character`.  Choose a font such as `DejaVu Serif` that contains the character, and find the symbol in the list by scrolling, or type `2717` in the box after `U+`.

The [Writing Hand](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/270d/index.htm) is another symbol that shows where to sign.

Comment: hey thanks i was thought that it is samting like that :)